# Google Cloud Storage: Removing TXT verification

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have a firebase project which uses its Firebase Storage feature. Now I have a requirement where the download URL should be from our own domain instead of storage.googleapis.com.

So in order to achieve that, I created a bucket with my own domain namely file.mydomain.com. During the bucket creation, domain verification required where I verified it by creating TXT in my domain DNS config.

After verification completed, I need to add CNAME that points to storage.googleapis.com. Since DNS does not allow TXT and CNAME of the same domain (file.mydomain.com) at the same time, I deleted the TXT before creating the CNAME. Everything works now, I can download my file from http://file.mydomain.com/myfile.

My question is, will it be alright that I deleted the TXT file? Will google do checking and trigger reverification?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Google does not ask you to create CNAME and TXT resource records with the same name. Google verifies the zone apex (example.com) and not the subdomain (file.example.com). What were the exact CNAME and TXT names? 2) In my experience (years), once verified Google does not reverify. However, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TXT file record is for verification purposes. According to these [answer1](https://support.google.com/a/thread/129037623/is-it-ok-to-delete-txt-records-after-verification?hl=en), [answer 2](https://support.google.com/a/thread/89550658/any-issue-if-we-remove-the-txt-verification-record-after-verification?hl=en) from Google Support is one-time verification, and once it has been verified, then it's safe to delete it.

Note: You can remove the TXT record, but not the MX records.